# React Native: Updating ListView issue

Tags: react-native

I need to update Listview when in textinput typed > 2 symbols. I get data from API, and every new symbol after 2 chars must update suggested variants (new datasource). Can't find my mistake. Will be very grateful for solution :)

Source code: 
https://rnplay.org/apps/msxitg

Comment: Please include the source code into the question itself. "Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is on row 54:

```
API_RESPONSE_ARRAY = responseJSON.result.items.name;
```

responseJSON.result.items is list of objects that have name key. You have to change this to following and it will work:

```
API_RESPONSE_ARRAY = responseJSON.result.items.map((item) => item.name);
```

Forked version that works can be found from here https://rnplay.org/apps/WDXSHw

ps. maybe you know it but as it is you don't need the componentWillReceiveProps function and it's not called at all currently.